# General - Guide to getting setup on testnet and solidity on a Mac

Tags: solidity, testrpc, mac-osx

I just purchased a new Macbook with the hopes of getting started developing dapps via solidity. Does anyone have a good resource/guide to getting started with testrpc on a mac?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I am starting here as it seems truffle is pretty widely used: http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/project.

I also found this intro to solidity useful: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/solidity/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.